# Cannot run jupyter notebook in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, python, jupyter

I have installed jupyter notebook using:

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter
```

It seemed to work but I got the error:

```
The directory '/home/user1/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/user1/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag
```

When I run it:

```
jupyter notebook
```

I get the error:

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Comment: The error about caching is a non-issue. That's just how pip works. Google it for more details.

Comment: What stoppping me is the second error, any idea how to get jupyter notebook to work?

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue. This is what I did to fix the issue (on Ubuntu 16.04):

```
sudo apt-get remove ipython
sudo apt-get purge ipython 
sudo apt-get autoremove
pip install jupyter
```

ipython seemed to be the problem, hence removing it fixed the issue.

I'm now able to run `jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the **warning** whenever using `sudo` with `pip` use the `-H` flag

```
sudo -H pip3 install jupyter
```

Or you can simply use the `--user` flag without `sudo`

```
pip3 install jupyter --user
```

The `--user` flag solves user ownership problems

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run it as root ?

```
sudo jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

or login as root and run the following command:

```
jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

Comment: I've just tried, doesn't work. I get the exact same error "Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 8] Exec format error"